# How to get user permissions for the role Administrator?

Tags: 8, users

I need to get permissions for all user roles, which are used. The code looks something like this:

```
$anonymous = Role::load('anonymous');
$anonymousPermissions = $anonymous->getPermissions();
```

The code for anonymous (and also for authenticated) returns an array of permissions, but the same code for administrator returns null:

```
$administrator = Role::load('administrator');
```

How can I get permissions for the role Administrator? (The machine name of role Administrator is administrator and also in the database is nothing suspicious.)

---

I have tried also:

```
$administratorPermissions = user_role_permissions(['administrator']);
```

It returns:

```
array(1) {
    ["administrator"] =>
        array(0) {
    }
}
```

---

If I try:

```
$roles = Role::loadMultiple();
foreach ($roles as $role => $rolesObj) {
    $role_list[$role] = $rolesObj->get('label');
}
print_r($role_list);
```

Then I get:

```
Array
(
    [anonymous] => Anonymous user
    [authenticated] => Authenticated user
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Role::getPermissions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3AgetPermissions/8.2.x) method code:

```
  /**
   * Returns a list of permissions assigned to the role.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The permissions assigned to the role.
   */
  public function getPermissions() {
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
      return [];
    }
    return $this->permissions;
  }
```

So, if the user has all permissions the returned value is an empty array.

Why? I really don't know and I can't find the answer, maybe other user knows [Why Role::getPermissions() method return an empty array for admin users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/233475/28275).

The good news is that you can get all the Administrator permission with this code:

```
array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions());
```

Test this code (You'll need the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to use `dpm()`):

```
$administrator = Role::load('administrator');
if($administrator->isAdmin()) {
  dpm(array_keys(\Drupal::service('user.permissions')->getPermissions()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a good solution and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AntonínSlejška you're welcome, and good luck with your project ;-)