# Why Role::getPermissions() method return an empty array for admin users?

Tags: 8, users

Searching the answer for [How to get user permissions for the role Administrator?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/233416/28275) I found that if you try to get the permissions for the admin user you will get an empty array.

From [Role::getPermissions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3AgetPermissions/8.2.x):

```
  /**
   * Returns a list of permissions assigned to the role.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The permissions assigned to the role.
   */
  public function getPermissions() {
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
      return [];
    }
    return $this->permissions;
  }
```

But if the admin user have all the permissions why Drupal just return an empty array?

Comment: Does this happen for "super admin" (user 1) only? or does this still happen even for other "admins" (admins that are not user 1) ?

Comment: @NoSssweat I haven't test it but I think that is for all the admin users `public function isAdmin() {
  return (bool) $this->is_admin;
}`

Comment: @NoSssweat It happens for all the users having the role that in admin/config/people/accounts you set as _Administrator role_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because a role that is marked with *is_admin* (which from the UI is possible for just a single role) has all the permissions. Consider it as an extension of the user #1 concept; the difference is that there is just a user #1, but there could be many users assigned to the role marked as *is_admin*.
In fact, the code does the same it does for the user #1: It explicitly checks for the role being *is_admin*. So, returning an array of permissions that will never be used doesn't make sense. See [`Role::hasPermission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3AhasPermission/8.2.x).

```
  if ($this->isAdmin()) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return in_array($permission, $this->permissions);
```

Similar code is present in other functions/methods, for example [Role::revokePermission()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3ArevokePermission/8.2.x).

```
  if ($this->isAdmin()) {
    return $this;
  }
  $this->permissions = array_diff($this->permissions, array($permission));
  return $this;
```

As for why Drupal uses that code, it is because from the UI it is possible to change which role is marked as *is_admin*, including one for which permissions were already set. Once it is marked *is_admin*, the permissions explicitly set can be ignored, but they are kept, just in case you change from the UI the role marked as *is_admin*. In such case, you would not want to set again the permissions you set for the old *is_admin* role.

Comment: makes sense, and interesting think about the permissions, thanks kiam.